# How to call a bash script from cmake and pass a generator dependent string as argument?

Tags: cmake, ninja

While using the `Unix Makefiles` generator I have added the following to a CMakeLists.txt file:

```
add_custom_target(maintainer-clean
  # The current directory is CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR.
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cwm4/scripts/cmake_maintainer_clean.sh $(MAKE) \"${GITACHE_PACKAGES}\"
)
```

This `cmake_maintainer_clean.sh` script is `make` specific, and it needs to use `$(MAKE)` in the generated Makefile when calling the script.

However, when switching to the generator `Ninja` this custom command is put as-is in the `build.ninja` file, causing the `$` of the `$(MAKE)` to cause problems (ninja refuses to run any target, failing to parse `build.ninja`).

Therefore, I wish to make this generator-specific. How can I use `$(MAKE)` as first argument to the script when the generator is `Unix Makefiles` and something else, without a `$` - e.g. `"ninja"` - when the generator is `Ninja`?

Can I do something like:

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cwm4/scripts/cmake_maintainer_clean.sh $<UNIX:$(MAKE),ninja> \"${GITACHE_PACKAGES}\"
```

?

Comment: The primary purpose of generator expressions is to specify information specific for a **build configuration** (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE). For all other conditions it is sufficient to use common `if` clause for set some variable: `if(CMAKE_GENERATOR STREQUAL "Ninja")`, `set(arg "MAKE")`, `else()`, `set(arg "$(MAKE)")`, `endif()` and use this variable as an argument for whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would make separate [presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) for each generator, so you can associate a particular environment variable with it. Here is how the **CMakePresets.json** file may look like:

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 20,
    "patch": 0
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "base",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
      "hidden": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Ninja",
      "inherits": "base",
      "displayName": "Ninja Config",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "environment": {
        "SCRIPT_ARG": "Ninja"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Make",
      "inherits": "base",
      "displayName": "Make Config",
      "generator": "Unix Makefiles",
      "environment": {
        "SCRIPT_ARG": "Make"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Where the `SCRIPT_ARG` can be read later inside of the **CMakeLists.txt** configuration:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(Hello)
add_executable(Hello main.cpp)

add_custom_target(my-script
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script.sh $ENV{SCRIPT_ARG}
)

add_dependencies(Hello my-script)
```

Providing `script.sh` is as simple as this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello from script, $1!"
```

You will end up with the following output during build phase:

```sh
% cmake --preset Make
...
% cmake --build build
Hello from script, Make!
[  0%] Built target my-script
...
```

Corresponding output for `Ninja` generator would be:

```sh
% cmake --preset Ninja
...
% cmake --build build
Hello from script, Ninja!
[  0%] Built target my-script
...
```

---

If you need something more complex than an environment variable, you can introduce condition statement based on value of [`CMAKE_GENERATOR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(Hello)
add_executable(Hello main.cpp)

if(CMAKE_GENERATOR STREQUAL Ninja)
  add_custom_target(my-script COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script.sh $ENV{SCRIPT_ARG})
elseif(CMAKE_GENERATOR STREQUAL "Unix Makefiles")
  add_custom_target(my-script COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/another_script.sh)
endif()


add_dependencies(Hello my-script)
```

---

The provided solutions work at build step, and for the part whether it's possible to distinguish between generators during build system generation phase (e.g. with use of [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)) i don't think it's possible, because the configuration is generator-agnostic at this point.